# Java-client для ClickHouse отправляет не все батчи

Tags: java, база-данных, clickhouse

Так отправляются 1000 объектов батчами по 50:

```
 void executeBatch(final List<V> batch) throws ClickHouseException {
        if (!batch.isEmpty()) {
            try (ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(ClickHouseProtocol.HTTP)) {
                ClickHouseRequest.Mutation insertRequest = client.read(cluster).write().table(tableName)
                    .format(ClickHouseFormat.RowBinary);
                ClickHouseConfig config = insertRequest.getConfig();

                try (final ClickHousePipedOutputStream stream = ClickHouseDataStreamFactory.getInstance()
                    .createPipedOutputStream(config, (Runnable) () -> log.info("After stream"))) {
                    insertRequest.data(stream.getInputStream())
                        .execute()
                        .thenAccept(response ->
                            LOGGER.info("Batch: {}, Written rows: {}", batch.size(),
                                response.getSummary().getWrittenRows()));

                    for (final V event : batch) {
                        BinaryStreamUtils.writeString(stream, event.get("id").getAsString());
                        BinaryStreamUtils.writeNonNull(stream);
                        BinaryStreamUtils.writeString(stream, event.get("name").getAsString());
                    }
                    log.info("Batch_created");
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw ClickHouseException.of(e, cluster.getTemplate());
            }
        }
    }
```

В логах есть сообщения про успешный инсерт, но их не 20, а каждый раз меньше:

> Batch: 50, Written rows: 50

Есть все 20 сообщений после создания батча:

> Batch_created

И все 20 про окончание стрима:

> After stream

Никаких ошибок в логах нет.
Но нет всех 20 сообщений об инсерте, их количество всегда разное, и в целевой таблице тоже не все строки.

В таблице system.errors появляются записи:

- Cannot parse input: expected '\r\n' at end of stream.
- Unexpected end of file while reading chunk header of HTTP chunked data
- Too many parts (300). Merges are processing significantly slower than inserts
- Directory /var/lib/clickhouse/store/1ae/1ae1dd8f-736f-4a7d9f15608a194c56af/tmp_merge_202307_178_275_1/ already exists

При перезапусках в целевой таблице всегда нет всех 1000 строк.

Вопрос- есть ли в коде ошибка, и почему ClickHouse не принимает все батчи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не работал с ClickHouse, но подозреваю что у вас клиент или стрим закрывается прежде чем асинхронная операция выполняется.
Поменяйте свой код в соответствии с примером в [документации](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java/blob/main/examples/client/src/main/java/com/clickhouse/examples/jdbc/Main.java#L39)

Comment: Мой код и взят и этого примера, только убрал блокировку .get(), чтобы не ждать окончания запроса. Если добавить, то всё работает, но смущает, что сама асинхронность тогда по сути не используется.

Comment: @Dmitry, а какая у Вас задача? Вызвать executeBatch несколько раз и чтобы каждый вызов выполнялся, условно параллельно (асинхронно)?

Comment: Есть ListenableThreadPool, в который при набирании батча отправляется Future с этим методом .executeBatch(). Те уже есть параллельные потоки, которые выполняют инсерт, но непонятно зачем их блокировать, и что значит в комменте из офф гита worker thread.  
"in async mode, which is default, execution happens in a worker thread"

Comment: Как я уже говорил, я никогда не работал с этой библиотекой, но, если вы не хотите ждать выполнения инсерта в вашем методе - вам тогда надо закрывать `client` после того как инсерт завершится. Т.е. либо вы передаете это клиент в метод `executeBatch` и закрываете его где-то в другом месте, когда все futures завершатся (опять же, надо будет где-то ждать их завершения), либо вы ждете внутри при помощи вызова `get()` - т.к. у вас все это уже выполняется асинхронно - ничего страшного в этом не будет.

Comment: Либо, вы как-то навешиваете закрытие клиента на событие завершения обработки (например вызовом метода `hanfle` вместо `thenAccept`).  
а коммент из документации, скорее всего означает это: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html, т.к. по умолчанию `CompletableFuture` выполняется при помощи `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` - см. javadoc